# Poping the value from Redis List in multi-threaded environment returns the duplicate value to few threads

Tags: redis, spring-batch

There some records in DB having association between cId & mId that i get by some complex db query. 
Use Case is to fetch the complete list of dataId corresponding to cId & mId combination and push it to redis. 
We get cId & mId combinations from the input csv file to my batch job. There will be multiple records corresponding to same combination in file
The batch job is configured with 10 parallel thread and threads one by read the records. All we want is when a thread reads particular combination from file, we get all the records from database and upload them to redis to resolve 2 problems :
1. Db hits
2. Concurrency issue i.e. two threads shouldn't get the same record from db based on cId & mId combination

```
private static Long DEFAULT_REDIS_OBJECTID = 0L;


        public DataObject getDataObject(C cId, M mId) {
                String redisListKey = new StringBuilder().append(LIST-).append(cId)
                        .append("-").append(mId).toString();
    if (BooleanUtils.isFalse(redisTemplate.hasKey(redisListKey))) {
                pushRedisData(cId, mId, redisListKey);
            }
        }
    Long dataId = redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop(redisListKey);
            if (Objects.isNull(dataId ) || 0L.equals(dataId )) {
//    Again creating the key in order to make sure another thread request for this should not shouldn't go in the db as we know we dont have data in db for this combination         
redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPush(redisListKey, 0L);
                //create a new dataObject and return it
            } else {
                //Get the dataObject based on dataId and return it
            }


    public synchronized void pushRedisData(Long cId, Long mId, String redisListKey) {
            if (BooleanUtils.isFalse(redisTemplate.hasKey(redisListKey))) {
                List<Long> dataToPush = dataService.getDataIdListFromCIdAndMIdCombination(cId,
                        mId);
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(dataToPush )) {
                    redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPushAll(redisListKey, dataToPush );
                    redisTemplate.expire(redisListKey, 5, TimeUnit.HOURS);
                } else {
                    if (redisTemplate.opsForList().size(redisListKey) == 0) {
                        redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPush(redisListKey, DEFAULT_REDIS_ITEMID);
                    }

                }
```

I have made the synchronized method to push the records to redis so that only one thread is able to publish the data to redis corresponding to key and other threads just pop the data from redis. 
In case there is no record found in database for any of cId & mId combination, then i'm creating the key on redis with default 0 value so that threads with such combination shouldn't go for DB call.

**Problem :** When i execute the batch job with 1000 records in file & 10 threads are configured to process these records, i see that 3-5 threads get the duplicate dataId which is already assigned to other threads and object is under process results in Stalestate exception for threads having duplicate dataId. 
I also found that this problem is encountered at starting phase of job for first few records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

You're running into race conditions because of a leaky synchronization.

## Explanation

The way you attempt to synchronize is leaky which allows multiple threads to do the same work. That's something you already noticed. There is no atomic block that guards two concurrent threads against executing the same statements - not speaking of locks here.

Introducing `synchronized` methods is likely to address the issue locally if you use the same object instances but that's not a solution. It will block other, concurrent threads preventing these from progressing.

Why don't you synchronize utilizing Redis' properties through e.g. a set?

You *could* use a Redis set to make sure that only a single thread/process is able to process an element by adding that particular element to the Redis set. Redis will respond whether adding that element was successful or not. This information will help you to resolve the race by inspecting the response. If the element could be added to the set then the current thread is the first one that hit your `dataId` and that one may continue with the expensive work (database fetch, …).

When adding an element to the synchronizing set fails then you know that some other process already is doing the expensive work and you can continue looking up data from the cache. You need to be aware that although another thread might have won the non-blocking synchronization, the other first thread is not necessarily done with populating the cache. You can then:

1. Poll the cache until the value is there.
2. Have a timeout (you can't be sure the other process is alive) and then do duplicate work to progress with your actual task.

Think also what's worse: Waiting for the cache value and blocking the import progress or querying your expensive data source multiple times. You can optimize for both case but you need to decide on your own.